# Why does CLion's integrated CMake fail to find installed packages?

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, clion

I have a C++ project described by a CMakeLists.txt file from which CMake successfully generates a MAKE file if I call CMake from the terminal. (This is on Ubuntu.)

The project has dependencies on Boost and Eigen which are both installed on my system. I can see the Boost includes in `/usr/include/boost`, Boost binaries in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`, and the Boost .cmake files in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/`. I see the Eigen headers in `/usr/include/eigen3` and `Eigen3Config.cmake` in `/usr/lib/cmake/eigen3`.

My CMakeLists.txt file calls `find_package` in config mode as below:

```
find_package(Eigen3 CONFIG REQUIRED)
if (${Eigen3_FOUND})
   Message(STATUS "eigen found...")
endif (${Eigen3_FOUND})

find_package(Boost 1.7 CONFIG REQUIRED QUIET)
if (${Boost_FOUND})
    Message(STATUS "boost found...")
endif (${Boost_FOUND})
```

The above works as expected from the command line but when I attempt to open the project from CLion 2020.2.3 i get the following error

> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package):   Could not find a
> package configuration file provided by "Eigen3" with any   of the
> following names:
>
> ```
> Eigen3Config.cmake
> eigen3-config.cmake
> ```
>
> Add the installation prefix of "Eigen3" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
> "Eigen3_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
> "Eigen3"   provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
> has been   installed.

If I change the order of the `find_package` calls CMake fails to find boost similarly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this behavior seems to have been a result of installing CLion as a flatpak package. I uninstalled and reinstalled as normal binaries and the problem goes away. (new to Linux here...)

This is the same issue as described here: [Jetbrains YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-23586). The take away seems to be do not install JetBrains products via Flatpak.